# Capture or data of a website

Tags: php, curl

I wanted to capture data of a website that is having funtionality of download data as html/pdf. But i want to capture that data without any download i tried with executing that url through curl on my local machine. When i run my that curl on my browser that opens up the page. 
I am not able to understand why this is happening.
My code is :

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://example.com/xyz.aspx",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query(array(
        'Cdate' => '02/05/2017',
        'ListType' => 'D',
        'ddlNo'=>0,
        'ddl'=>0,
        'txtCaseNo'=>'',
        'Gen'=>'Search List',
        'txt'=>'XYZ'
    ))
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

the parameters are defined the curl request are the parameters that are used with the request.

Comment: *I am not able to understand why this is happening* Why is what happening?

Comment: Please also why you are rating it down?

Comment: I didn't vote :/

Comment: Instead of getting data the page is getting opening in my browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the result contains a javascript redirect? Maybe try something like this:

```
print_r(htmlentities($result));
```

instead of:

```
print_r($result);
```